# Why PostConstruct method does not work to keep bean init order when using in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some config information in the database, when the springboot starts, it will load this information only one time.  So I write the code like this:

```
@Configuration 
public class CommonConfig {
    private final DbConfigDao dbConfigDao;

    @Autowired
    public CommonConfig (DbConfigDao dbConfigDao) {
        this.dbConfigDao = dbConfigDao;
    }

    private int redisStoreDays; //omit get,set method
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { 
        redisStoreDays = dbConfigDao.getValueByKey("redisStoreDays");
        //... continue to load the other config from db 
    }
}
```

In the other bean, I try to get the `redisStoreDays` value, it returns `0`, but the real value is `1`.

```
@Configuration 
public class  AutoConfiguration {

    @Conditional(RedisClusterConditional.class)
    @Bean(name = "redisDao", initMethod = "init")
    public RedisClusterDao getRedisClusterDao() {
        return new RedisClusterDaoImpl();
    }

    @Conditional(RedisSentryConditional.class)
    @Bean(name = "redisDao", initMethod = "init")
    public RedisSentryConditional getRedisSentryDao() {
        return new RedisSentryDaoImpl(); 
    }
}

public class RedisClusterDaoImpl implements RedisDao {  
    @Autowired
    private CommonConfig commonConfig; 
    private int storeDays = 7;  

    @Override
    public void init()  { 
        storeDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * commonConfig.getRedisStoreDays(); 
        //commonConfig.getRedisStoreDays is 0 but in fact is 1 
    }  
}
```

How to keep the bean init order?
I try to add PostConstruct in my redis bean, but it still does not work.

I debug and find the `commonConfig` is not null, but `commonConfig.getRedisStoreDays()` returns `0`.

After executing `init` method in `RedisClusterDaoImpl`, `commonConfig.getRedisStoreDays()` changes to 1.

I also try to add **@AutoConfigureBefore(RedisClusterDao.class)**，but `storeDays` still gets `0` in `RedisClusterDaoImpl` class.

Comment: Can you log something in both init methods and see what is the order of the execution? Just to rule out that the order is not the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't go around mixing configurations with normal beans, even though technically the configuration is a component. Why not just offer the config Dao as a bean? Or at least initialize the days var when the Dao is injected, not in a post construct.

Comment: @Suman,How to rule out? Now the order is not what I want.

Comment: @daniu,nitialize the days var when the Dao is injected,How to write?config Dao is already a bean and is injected in commonConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring's `@DependsOn`, i.e.:

```
@DependsOn("CommonConfig")
@Configuration
public class AutoConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
@Configuration 
public class CommonConfig {
    private final DbConfigDao dbConfigDao;

    @Autowired
    public CommonConfig (DbConfigDao dbConfigDao) {
        this.dbConfigDao = dbConfigDao;
        // why in PostConstruct? You have the bean right here, it should be initialized
        redisStoreDays = dbConfigDao.getValueByKey("redisStoreDays");
    }

    private int redisStoreDays; //omit get,set method
    
}
```

or just

```
public class RedisClusterDaoImpl implements RedisDao {  
    @Autowired
    private DbConfigDao commonConfig; 
    private int storeDays = 7;  

    @Override
    public void init()  { 
        storeDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * dbConfigDao.getValueByKey("redisStoreDays");
    }  
}
```

After all, this is the redis bean, I don't see why it shouldn't know the name of the config setting it needs.

Comment: The first method is not ok,my construct method is without parameter like new RedisSentryDaoImpl().

Comment: @flower I don't know what you mean. I didn't change the constructor you posted.